# Is it correct to refer to a higher-order function as a "template"?

Tags: javascript, templates, ecmascript-6, terminology, higher-order-functions

**Minimal example:** Say I have the higher-order function

`const my_fn = (a) => (b) => a + b`

that, when called like so:

`my_fn(42)`

returns the function `(b) => 42 + b`.

Would it be correct to refer to `my_fn` as a "template function"?

I know that, in languages such as C++, the word "template" has a very specific technical meaning.
But in JavaScript, there is (AFAIK) no built-in template in syntax in the way that there is in C++.

I don't want to abuse terminology.

**Is it correct to refer to higher-order functions in JS as template functions, and vice-versa?**

(related, optional question: is there a difference between skillfully using higher-order functions in JS and doing "generic programming" in this language?)

Comment: I don't think the word template applies in the context of JS, so I wouldn't expect to ever use that word in a JS conversation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a “template” function, though I might call this function a “function factory.” To me, the word “template” in languages like C++ implies the specific goal of applying one function to a range of different data types.

A function like the example you gave doesn’t really accomplish anything new in terms of “generic programming” because it's not designed to produce functions that operate on different types of values. Javascript is not strict about types, so you can pass a value of any type to your function and the language will do its best to work with it. You don't have to do anything additional to make a function apply to different types of objects; every function accepts every kind of object unless the programmer adds explicit typechecking logic.

Comment: Would it be correct then to say that every template function is a function factory (since it creates a new function for each given combo of types) but that not all function factories are templates (since not all function factories have the goal of making a single function work with many types)?

Comment: Sure, I think that makes sense.